# Making a hollow box in Python to these specifications?

Tags: python

I'm to "Write a python program that prompts the user to input a positive integer n. The program then prints a hollow rectangle with n rows and 2*n columns. For a example an input of 3 would output:"

```
******
*    *
******
```

And my code is:

```
n=int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
for col in range(n):
    for row in range(n):
        print('*' if col in(0,(2*n)+1) or row in(0,n+1) else ' ', end=' ')
    print()
```

But my output doesn't look at all like what I need; it's like the upper and left half of a hollow box. In addition, I'm not getting double columns like I need. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Thank you everyone for your help! Gave me a lot of insight and was very helpful. I modified my code to the following, and it works very well:

```
>n=int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
>for row in range(n):
>    for col in range(2*n):
>        print('*' if row in(0,n-1) or col in(0,(2*n)-1) else ' ', end=' ')
>    print()
```

Special shout out to user2357112; you made me realize exactly what I had tripped up.

Comment: Kindly format your question properly. :) Otherwise people will start down voting you.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed it was poorly formatted and attempted to fix it myself. By the time I had it right you already got it for me :)

Comment: You have your loops backward; you have to finish printing an entire row before moving on to the next, not an entire column. Also, you're only looping over `n` columns, and you have the boundary checks wrong. The last row is row `n-1`, not `n+1`, and the last column is `2*n-1`, not `2*n+1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
# Response to StackOverflow post:
# Making a hollow box in Python

# The multiplication operator (*) is the same as repeated
# concatenation when applied to strings in Python.

# I solved the problem by creating an array with N elements
# and gluing them together (str.join(array)) with newline
# characters.

# I trust you're already familiar with string formatting and
# concatenation, but in case you're not, please feel free to
# ask for clarification.


def main():
    n = int (input("Enter an integer between 1 and 15"))
    box = "\n".join(["*"*(2*n)] + ["*%s*" % (" "*(2*n-2))]*(n-2) + ["*"*(int(n>1)*2*n)])
    print (box)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    input() # Prevents the console from closing immediately
```

As for your solution. it seems to me like the loop conditions are messed up; the column and row loops are in reverse order and the argument to range() in the column loop should be 2*n (since that's the number of columns intersecting each row). You should also take a second look at the conditions in the first print statement.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be like:

```
line =  "*"*(2*n)
print line
s  = "*" + " "*(n-2) + "*"
for i in range(n-2):
    print s
print line
```

The line:

```
"*"*(2*n)
```

specifies a string of "*", repeated 2*n times. You wanted 2*n column right.. This prints 2*n "*"

Comment: When I tried running this code I got a syntax error. In addition, I don't understand the purpose of the asterisk here between the quoted asterisk and (2*n)?

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
def printStars(length):
    l = ['*'*length]
    l+= ['*' + ' '*(length-2) + '*'] * (length-2)
    l+= ['*'*length]

    return l

if __name__=='__main__':
    print('\n'.join(printStars(15)))
```

**Output:**

```
***************
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
***************
```

Hope this helps :)

EDIT:Fixed Some Formatting

Comment: No this does not vary according to the value of length. there should be number of rows equal to length. Which you do not accomplish

Comment: Oops Sorry Aswin, I ve edited the code accordingly. Thanks for the head on. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_box():       
    size = int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
    for i in range(size):
        if i == 0 or i == size - 1:
            print("*"*(size+2))
        else:
            print("*" + " "*size + "*")


make_box()
```

**Output:** (n=15)

```
*****************
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*****************
```

Comment: Did I misinterpret your question to make a bigger hollow box :p

Answer (score 0):

My solution is more elementary. Please consider it :

```
row = abs(eval(input('Enter row: ')))
col = abs(eval(input('Enter column: ')))
print ('*'*col)

for i in range (row-2):
      print ('*'+' '*(col-2)+'*')
print ('*'*col)
```

Comment: Hello, after reading [answer]. please [edit] your answer and elaborate it why it fixes the problem as advice. Thanks